# Select() issue in C

Tags: c, sockets, serversocket

so here is my issue, I have a server which invokes this code upon a client connecting, the problem is, once a client invokes, it ends up in an infinite loop and I can't figure out why. I expect the code to wait again on the Select for another client to connect, but instead, the initial trigger continues to result in a never ending loop.

output when ONE client connects:

```
Lets startYOOHELLO WORLD WE MATCH
Lets startYOOHELLO WORLD WE MATCH
...
.
.
.
..
```

Comment: Your socket is readable (has some data to be read), but does a component actually reads out of there?

Comment: @barmatat read returns the 'hi' or whatever, the client sent, so I know that's fine, but I expect to once again block on the select so it can wait for future clients. Instead, as per GDB, on the 2nd run, despite no client connecting it somehow thinks its okay to enter the select, not wait, and continue going forward, where as on the initial run it waits in the Select

Comment: Ok, select says that you can perform an op over the socket, so my question was - are you sure you do the op, before falling back to the select call? I mean read all data until you read 0 bytes or wrtie data there etc. I don't see this in your code.

Comment: @barmatat yes I am doing that, but for now showing that is unnecessary, you can assume I print a hello world when a client connects for now, and now I want to wait again for another client to connect so I can AGAIN print hello world

Comment: Your code that you posted to the question selects sockets that are ready for read (have some data). This code doesn't show how you accept new connections or how it reads something. From my point of view it does what you wrote - it will be in infinite loop if a socket from fd_set is ready for read. Your question statement and code you posted are inconsistent then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are stuck in infinite loop is because `you are not accepting new connections from the clients` in your infinite loop & the file/socket descriptors that are in your structure array `are not valid any more` because those *clients have terminated.* You have chosen a very poor mechanism of using select.

You should do the like this:

```
while(1)
{
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);

    //add master socket to set
    FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
    max_sd = master_socket;

    //add child sockets to set
    for ( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++) 
    {
        //socket descriptor
        sd = client_socket[i];

        //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list
        if(sd > 0)
            FD_SET( sd , &readfds);

        //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function
        if(sd > max_sd)
            max_sd = sd;
    }

    //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL , so wait indefinitely
    activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);

    if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR)) 
    {
        printf("select error");
    }

    //If something happened on the master socket , then its an incoming connection
    if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds)) 
    {
        if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
            perror("accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands
        printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d \n" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));

        //send new connection greeting message
        if( send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0) != strlen(message) ) 
        {
            perror("send");
        }

        puts("Welcome message sent successfully");

        //add new socket to array of sockets
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) 
        {
            //if position is empty
            if( client_socket[i] == 0 )
            {
                client_socket[i] = new_socket;
                printf("Adding to list of sockets as %d\n" , i);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //else its some IO operation on some other socket :)
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) 
    {
        sd = client_socket[i];

        if (FD_ISSET( sd , &readfds)) 
        {
            //Check if it was for closing , and also read the incoming message
            if ((valread = read( sd , buffer, 1024)) == 0)
            {
                //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print
                getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&address , (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
                printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n" , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));

                //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse
                close( sd );
                client_socket[i] = 0;
            }

            //Echo back the message that came in
            else
            {
                //set the string terminating NULL byte on the end of the data read
                buffer[valread] = '\0';
                send(sd , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );
            }
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the master socket?

Comment: why do you use a master socket

Comment: @user2879618 It is the socket descriptor you passed to bind, listen or simply the socket descriptor returned by socket()

Answer (score 0):

If your server only wants to accept connections, then you should only select on the original socket FD.  You should NOT select on the new FD from an accept.